# drools convert drl to pkg incorrect error info

Tags: drools

I have a a.drl file and it works.   For a.drl, its header looks like :

```
package com.test.drools; 

import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Map; 
import com.temp.ToDoItemTO; 
import com.util.*;
```

I added these jars into build path.

I want to convert it into .pkg file with following code :

```
KnowledgeBuilder kBuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(); 
kBuilder.add( ResourceFactory.newFileResource( drlFile ), ResourceType.DRL ); 
if( kBuilder.hasErrors() ){ 
    for( KnowledgeBuilderError err: kBuilder.getErrors() ){ 
        System.err.println( err.toString() ); 
    } 
    throw new IllegalStateException( "DRL errors" ); 
} 
OutputStream os; 
    try { 
            os = new FileOutputStream( pkgFile ); 
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( os ); 
                oos.writeObject( kBuilder.getKnowledgePackages() ); 
                oos.close(); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

but it gives me many errors like next :

```
[Line: 3768, Column: 2] : [Rule name='remove scheduled event_351'] 

Unable to Analyse Expression p.estActionDate2Loc != null: 
[Error: com/icil/service/exception/entity/ApplicationException] 
[Near : {... p.estActionDate2Loc != null ....}]
```

Line 3768 is :

```
when 
    holder : MultiHolder(p: previousTO, p.estActionDate2Loc != null) 
then 
 .....
```

after tried again and again, i added this jar of com/icil/service/exception/entity/ApplicationException to build path, then errors disappear.

my confuses are :

1. a.drl header doesn't import com/icil/service/exception/entity/ApplicationException, why need to add it to build path,
2. even if i missed jar of com/icil/service/exception/entity/ApplicationException, why the error is not class not found instead of "unable to analyse expression p.estActionDate2Loc ..."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, if any of the classes in `com.util.*` reference any class which in turn references that exception, then you need to import it. However, the error you posted above is not a class not found exception. It would appear that your DRL is throwing that exception. I would be surprised if that would compile.

Comment: btw - I would expect that it's the `estActionDate2Loc` (or perhaps `getEstActionDate2Loc()`?) method which is throwing that exception.

Comment: @Steve, estActionDate2Loc is just a property of class,  getEstActionDate2Loc() just return value from a map, so maybe the exception not thrown from them. What I confused is : How to know what the error is exactly.  If just see the error above "Unable to resolve ...", it's hard to think I missed 'ApplicationException' in build path.  It seems that there is other code to compile .drl and can give the correct error info, but I can't find the code now.

Comment: The error above doesn't say "Unable to resolve"... ;)

Comment: The details of the declarations of MultiHolder.previousTO and MultiHolder.previousTO.estActionDate2Loc might help to clarify this. I would not write `p.estActionDate2Loc`, which is confusing. The straightforward way is `previousTO.estActionDate2Loc != null`. (BTW: does this change anything?)

Comment: I was about to mention that. :)  I wasn't aware of support for accessing the `p` variable in the same match (certainly none of the docs I can find show such an example). My suspicion is that with the current code, Drools might be looking for a method called `getP()` on the `MultiHolder` class.

Comment: @laune use `previousTO.estActionDate2Loc != null` doesn't change anything, the error is the same `Unable to Analyse Expression previousTO.estActionDate2Loc != null: 
[Error: com/icil/service/exception/entity/ApplicationException] 
[Near : {... previous.estActionDate2Loc != null ....}]`. Drools 5.5 Final is being used.